# SQL - Find all possible combination

Tags: sql

I need help finding all possible combination of value in database, for Example i have this table:

```
ITEM_SET           Support  
I1               0.244999999
I2               0.274999999     
I3               0.258333333    
I4               0.103333333
```

i need to find all possible combination like this :

```
I1,I2    I1,I2,I3    I1,I2,I3,I4
I1,I3    I1,I2,I4
I1,I4    I1,I3,I4
I2,I3    I2,I3,I4
I2,I4 
I3,I4
```

*Please note that this formatting meant only to help reading, as what i need is only a list of the possible combination like this Table:

```
ITEMSET
I1               
I2                    
I3                 
I4  
I1,I2    
I1,I3    
I1,I4    
I2,I3    
I2,I4 
I3,I4
I1,I2,I3 
I1,I2,I4 
I1,I3,I4 
I2,I3,I4   
I1,I2,I3,I4
```

Comment: Which flavor of SQL/RDBMS? E.g. MySql, Sql Server, Oracle etc.?

Comment: Seconded. While my answer covers a pseudo-ANSI SQL approach that works in MySQL, having more context might give us potential optimizations. I'm still interested in the main problem you're trying to tackle, though.

Comment: i'm working with msaccess, refer to my comment below for the big picture. in short it's a part of apriori algorithm

Answer (score 3):

What you're suggesting is an n! combination of all of the elements for lengths 1-n. Ignoring the possibility of using a code generator to create your elements, you could do something like this for each combination (in MySQL):

One item:

`SELECT item from ITEM_SET;`

Two items:

`SELECT one.item,two.item from ITEM_SET as one, ITEM_SET as two where one.item != two.item;`

Three items:

`SELECT one.item,two.item,three.item from ITEM_SET as one, ITEM_SET as two, ITEM_SET as three where one.item != two.item and one.item != three.item and two.item != three.item;`

Rinse and repeat. To be pedantic, I define *ITEM_SET* as my table name and *item* as my attribute, which is a more meaningful table composition.

This and the related question are code smells to me, though. If you're walking all permutations of elements programmatically for all candidate answers, there's likely a much simpler algorithm to solve your problem. Given your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352082/sql-query-combining-2-value-and-find-all-transaction-containing-that-value) is directly related to this one, perhaps you can offer more background information?

Comment: yup it's related :D since there's low response on my other question i divide the problem into smaller stack :) here's the big picture [Data Mining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349698/sql-data-mining-operation-using-sql-query-fuzzy-apriori-algorithm-how-do-i)

Comment: Here's some rep. Comment away. ;-) Nice answer btw.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most simple algorithms for generating combinations is bit counting.
**Pseudo-code**

```
N items, indexed 1-N

for i=1 to 2^N-1 
   for each bit in i
      if bit is set, output item[i]
```

Example for N=4:

```
N = 4, 2^4 = 16
i = 1:  binary = 00000001 -> output I1
i = 2:  binary = 00000010 -> output I2
i = 3:  binary = 00000011 -> output I1, I2
i = 4:  binary = 00000100 -> output I3
i = 6:  binary = 00000101 -> output I1, I3
i = 7:  binary = 00000111 -> output I1, I2, I3
i = 8:  binary = 00001000 -> output I4
i = 9:  binary = 00001001 -> output I1, I4
i = 10: binary = 00001010 -> output I2, I4
i = 11: binary = 00001011 -> output I1, I2, I4
i = 12: binary = 00001100 -> output I3, I4
i = 13: binary = 00001011 -> output I1, I2, I4
i = 14: binary = 00001110 -> output I2, I2, I4
i = 15: binary = 00001111 -> output I1, I2, I3, I4
```