# Can I make a integer field with bit information and use index?

Tags: sql, postgresql, bitwise-operators

Im trying to solve a puzzle *[more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42895607/how-create-all-pieces-combinations)*. So I have pieces and solutions created with those pieces.

```
 Pieces: piece_id
 Solution: solution_id
```

If I have three pieces will have 8 solutions ***2^3***. My idea is use `solution_id` to indicate what pieces are part of it.

```
 solution_id   pieces 
      0          000  -- no pieces (not really a solution)
      1          001  -- only the piece_id = 1
      2          010  -- only the piece_id = 2
      3          011  -- have piece 1 and 2
      4          100
      5          101
      6          110
      7          111  -- all pieces (not really a solution because need solve two parts)
```

I will need two solutions, but `solution2` cant have any pieces on `solution1`

The questions are:

- Can I do bitwise operation between integers to know if two solutions share any pieces or need a bit array?
- Can I use one index to improve the perfomance of this join?
- There is a better way to do this?

  ```
  SELECT s1.solution_id, s2.solution_id
  FROM solutions
  WHERE s1.solution_id & s2.solution_id = 0
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to know the answers to your questions:

1. Yes, you can use bitwise operations.
2. You probably cannot use indexes to optimize this query.

However, you could store the data differently.  The better data structure is:

```
solution_id    piece
   1             1
   2             2
   3             1
   3             2
. . .
```

Then you could use joins and more traditional database operations.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if bit array would be better option for this case.  I already have that structure. To store the pieces is good. But to find what pair of solution doesnt have same pieces is very complicated. Maybe you can take a look at this demo. http://rextester.com/GGGUTW70272